# Exclude a QuerySet from a pre-existing filtered QuerySet based on a One-to-One relationship

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a Django application with three models:

```
class Strategy(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...

class Version(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    strategy = models.ForeignKey(Strategy, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...

class Tool(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    version = models.OneToOneField(Version, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

On the Tool model's corresponding ToolForm, I filter the QuerySet for the 'version' field, so that the User only sees the strategy versions they submitted:

```
def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['version'].queryset = Version.objects.filter(strategy__user=user.id)
```

I now want to filter this QuerySet further to exclude Versions which already have Tools. The Version to Tool relationship is One-to-One, and I only want the User to see Versions which still require Tools to be submitted. I have tried numerous approaches, but I keep coming back to versions of:

```
Version.objects.filter(strategy__user=user.id).exclude(Tool.objects.filter(version__strategy__user=user.id).values('version_id'))

Version.objects.filter(strategy__user=user.id).exclude(Tool.objects.filter(version__strategy__user=user.id).values_list('version_id'))
```

Both "exclude" queries return the One-to-One field 'version_id' for the Tool entries. Respectively, the responses I get are:

```
'dict' object has no attribute 'split'
'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'
```

What am I missing? How can I exclude Versions from my ToolForm 'version' field that already have the One-to-One relationship established?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need exclude here. You can simply use [`tool__isnull=True`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#std:fieldlookup-isnull):

```
Version.objects.filter(strategy__user=user.id, tool__isnull=True)
```

Due to OneToOne relation between Version and Tool instances, Version has a field named `tool`(all lowercase model name unless you defined `related_name`). For Version instances which does not have Tool, the field will be empty. So `isnull=True` will check for Version instances which does not have any tool.

Comment: That worked, thanks; but why don't I see Version's 'tool' field in my database?  Initially, I thought there would be such a field, but I didn't see one going through the database. Of course, I can see the Tool 'version_id' field, which I assumed to be the field defining the relationship.

Comment: it is handled by django just like related name(reverse relations between models).